# AchartEngine Time Chart shifted to the right

Tags: android, achartengine

I'm using AChartEngine library for Android and in time charts the x labels do not correspond to points on the graph as you can see in images.

[image: Screen 1]

[image: Screen 2]

It appears that the graph is slightly shifted to the right.
Any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be fixed using this:

```
renderer.setXRoundedLabels(false);
```